# How to create shapes in HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a shape whose coordinates are based on the result from a query.

like for example

```
$query="SELECT COORDS_X, COORDS_Y from..... ";
```

Then I'll put the value of `COORDS_X` and `COORDS_Y` in two varaiables.

But what I don't know is the creation of the Shape. How can I create it and assign the coordinates of it form the value of `COORDS_X` and `COORDS_Y`?

Is there anyone who can assist/help me with my problem? I want to put the shape above a div (the div has an image inside). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a canvas to serve your purpose?? :)

Comment: SVG is great for shapes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch values from AJAX or create variables in JavaScript and then you can use any of canvas drawing tools like Raphael :

http://raphaeljs.com/

Small Circle can be drawn like this :

```
var cordX=110;
var cordY=35;
var paper = Raphael("sample-1", 200, 75);
var circle = paper.circle(cordX, cordY, 25);
circle.attr({fill: "blue"});
```

Where sample-1 is an ID of a div you want your shape in.

Here's a small demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/7k8s0f35/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good day @AkshatG Thank you for your response. Can i ask if it is also possible to create many shapes using array? i already created one in visual basic since i know that language but in javascript.. i'm still a newbie. this is my query.. "Sql = "select coords_x,coords_y FROM lots where lot_state='available'""

Comment: Yes definitely. Convert query response in JSON format. You will get lots of help online in converting php query response to json. Parse JSON in JavaScript and create an array. And then using loops you can create many shapes as well.

Comment: It's not working when i downloaded the raphael.js and added a 
  `<script src="scripts/raphael.js"></script>` may i know what i've done wrong? i just added a style in the head of my html file and div on the body and also script in the body (like the one you created) and tried it offline

Comment: are the php file or html file and raphael.js in the same directory ? Give me the structure and html code.

Comment: yes. but the rapahel.js is in scripts folder.  this is the file i created. `<!DOCTYPE html>  <html> <head> <style type="text/css">  #sample-1{  
    width:100px;  
    height:100px;  
}  
</style>  

</head>   
<body>  
<div id="sample-1"></div>  

<script language="JavaScript">  
var cordX=100;  
var cordY=365;  
var paper = Raphael("sample-1", 200, 75);  
var circle = paper.circle(cordX, cordY, 25);  
circle.attr({fill: "blue"});</script>  

        <script src="scripts/raphael.js"></script>  
</body>  
</html>  `

Comment: is there a way i can use raphaeljs offline? is yes, where can i download it and how can i include it? maybe i'm wrong it downloading the file and in the way i include it

Comment: You were using your script first and then adding raphael.js. That's not correct. Add raphael.js first. Secondly your Raphael paper size should be greater than your coordinates. Try this : `var paper = Raphael("sample-1", 1200, 1075);` Adjust according to your need.

Comment: it's now working. thank you so much :) can you give me an example of creating shapes based from an array?

Comment: What all shapes you want to create ?

Comment: I want to add shapes based on an array created from this query `$query=dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT LOT_X, LOT_Y from lot_details where LOT_STATE="available");`

Comment: Which shapes you want to add ?

Comment: `var circle = paper.circle(cordX, cordY, 5);
circle.attr({fill: "green"});</script>`

Comment: by the way, is it possible to click those shapes that will direct to another webpage?

Comment: You only want to add circle then it easy. And yeah its quite possible  to redirect to another webpage. Heres javascript for that: `var pointsArray=[[52,55],[80,100],[120,150]];

var cordX=110;
var cordY=35;
var paper = Raphael("sample-1", 1200, 1075);

for(var i=0;i<pointsArray.length;i++){
    var circle = paper.circle(pointsArray[i][0], pointsArray[i][1], 25);
 circle.attr({fill: "blue"});
    
    circle.click(function(e) {
                        location.href="www.google.com";
                        });
}`

Comment: but it doesn't display anything?

Comment: In your static page or on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Add your redirect code in the comment line  "location href here "

Comment: on the page itself. i tried running the link you commented, it's working but when i copied everything and tried running it, it's not :(

Comment: i know i'm asking too much, but this will be the last (for now. haha) but is it also possible to pass the location of the shape to another webpage when clicked? and how?

Comment: You need to pass it in URL as query string. Like : www.example.com?x=6&y=8. Use javascipt variables to pass the value. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: again, Thank you @AkshatG :)